# What is the use of $schema property use in the tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I see  `$schema` property used by some best practice tools like [@tsconfigs/node16](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tsconfig/node16) etc.

What is the use of this property? The contents of the URL pointing to the $schema property has keys that are not directly present in tsconfig.json but rather seems to influence the definition of the tsconfig properties itself.

Eg. https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig

I tried exploring the property typescript documentation but did not find any there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reference to the [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) that the document adheres to.

The schema describes the structure and format of the JSON document, and can also be used to validate the document.

Comment: So this validates the tsconfig.json?

Comment: Why would these libraries need to do that? Won't TS itself do it while initialising?

Comment: It defines the format of the `tsconfig.json` and can be used to validate it. What libraries are you referring to?

Comment: https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/main/bases/node18.json

Comment: That library provides bases for your TS config files. It restricts the options you can use in your TS config. The way it restricts that is by narrowing the standard TS config schema.

Comment: thanks. So $schema has nothing to do with tsconfig but rather a JSON level property?

Comment: A TSConfig file is a JSON document. To describe the structure and format that a TSConfig file needs to adhere to, a [JSON schema](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#schema) is used. That schema can also be used to check whether a TSConfig file is valid or not. The library that you refer to offers base TSConfig files for various scenarios. To describe what these TSConfig files are supposed to look like, they also use a JSON schema.